# Split text SQL text

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm working on a small project but hit a small obstacle.

So I'm currently able to sent/receive text messages and store them into a database.
Now i'm working on a trigger, but I'm quite stuck on something.

The text arrives in the table inbox and the information i need is in the column: textdecoded. The text is always something like:

1 stop 5
(int as ID, start/stop, int)

Now my question is,

how do I define a function that splits this record and places the ID in action.id, the start/stop in action.action and the last int into action.time (note: action.time is defined as an int not as a time))

Thanks in advance everybody :)
Kind regards,
David

Comment: Oh, and what's a _database inbox_?

Comment: I have nothing so far, probably been up too long working on it, but I really want it done by Monday. the database inbox should've been table Inbox :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `SQL Server` you can do something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION PARSE_STRING(@text NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO --yourTable--
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(@text, 0, PATINDEX('%st%', @text)), 
        SUBSTRING(@text, PATINDEX('%st%', @text), CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@text, PATINDEX('%st%', @text), LEN(@text)))),
        SUBSTRING(@text, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@text, PATINDEX('%st%', @text), LEN(@text))) + LEN(@text) - LEN(SUBSTRING(@text, PATINDEX('%st%', @text), LEN(@text))), LEN(@text))

    END
```

Also, here is a working **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22646)**.

Then after creating the function, you can call it in your trigger, or wherever else you'd like.

Comment: Oh, 1 second more, I have to tweak it a bit :-). I'll post a link to a working fiddle also.

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when column_name like '%stop%' then 
substring('column_name ' ,1,charindex('stop','column_name ',1)-1)
          ,'stop'
      ,substring('column_name ' ,charindex('stop','column_name ',1)+5,1
         )
       case when column_name like '%start%' then 
substring('column_name ' ,1,charindex('start','column_name ',1)-1)
          ,'start'
      ,substring('column_name ' ,charindex('start','column_name ',1)+6,1
         )    
from table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Inbox as varchar(15)
SET @Inbox = '1 start 5'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Inbox,1,PATINDEX('% %',@Inbox)) AS ID,
       SUBSTRING(@Inbox,PATINDEX('% %',@Inbox),PATINDEX('% %',RIGHT(@Inbox,LEN(@Inbox)-PATINDEX('% %',@Inbox)))) AS Action,
       RIGHT(@Inbox,PATINDEX('% %',REVERSE(@Inbox))) AS ActionTime
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this trigger:

```
create trigger inbox_cascade 
on inbox 
for insert 
as
  begin
  declare @txt varchar(max)
  declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
  declare c cursor for select replace(textdecoded,' ',''',''') from inserted
  open c
  fetch next from c into @txt
  while @@fetch_status=0
    begin
    set @cmd='insert into action (id,action,time) values('''+@txt+''')'
    exec sp_executesql @cmd
    fetch next from c into @txt
    end
  close c
  deallocate c
end
```

Comment: `from inbox` should be `from inserted`, otherwise the statement breaks if inbox contains more than 1 record. plus your trigger does not handle inserting multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I got the following after some intense thinking and taking a break:

```
declare @failureId int
    declare @action varchar(200)
    declare @time int
    declare @input varchar(200)
    declare @input2 varchar(200)
    declare @alertId int

    select @input = (select textdecoded from inserted)
    select @failureId = substring(@input, 1, charindex(' ',@input)-1)

    select @input2 = substring(@input, charindex(' ',@input)+1, LEN(@input) - charindex(' ', @input)+1)
    select @action = substring(@input2, 1, charindex(' ', @input2)-1)

    select @time = substring(@input2, charindex(' ',@input2)+1, LEN(@input) - charindex(' ', @input)+1)

    select @alertId = (select id from Alert where failureId = @failureId)

    insert into Action values (@alertId, @failureId, @action, @time)
```

I realize it isn't a perfect piece of code, but it's working for me :)
Thanks everybody for the help on this matter :) your suggestions and ideas gave me the push i needed :D

MANY MANY THANKS :D